# Product of Pareto RV and Normal RV : PDF and other characteristics

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am struggling to find the PDF of a product of two random variables.

$ a = x \times h$

$ x \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu, \sigma^2 )$

$ h \sim \mathcal{P} (\alpha, x_m)$

I know the PDF's of the two Random Variables separately, but how can I find the PDF of the product?

Edit: The two variables are independent of each other

Comment: Are the two random variables independent?

Comment: @JimmyR. Yes they are